# Write Js from C# api

Tags: javascript

There is an advert displayed on this site about an API to write javascript from C#. Does anyone have the link for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://sharpkit.net/

Comment: Thanks! That's just the one. Is a slight waste of a thread as the ad comes up ocassionally.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp).